# Semantic Mediawiki not tracking redirects

Tags: mediawiki, semantics, mediawiki-templates, semantic-mediawiki

I have a few pages that I recently renamed (and updated all of the redirects), and ever since that time none of their redirects have been appearing in `{{#ask}}` queries based on their pagenames. For example, I have a page that I renamed from Infliximab to PF-06438179, and it has 26 redirects. Before, a template on the page with a query of the form

```
{{#ask: [[category:clinical studies]] [[compound number::{{PAGENAME}}]] ... }}
```

listed 53 pages, but ever since the move it only lists the 6 that direct-link to the page (and ignores the 47 that link to redirects).

- I've performed dummy-edits on all of the redirects multiple times to try to refresh the index
- I've performed dummy-edits on the page and the template to try to refresh the `{{#ask}}` function
- I've performed dummy-edits on a few of the pages linking to redirects to try to refresh the semantic tags
- I've completed a data repair cycle via the SMW admin panel
- I've had my sysadmin run `refreshLinks.php`

None of these has corrected the problem. How do I make SMW rediscover these redirects? Thanks!

- Semantic MediaWiki 1.8
- MediaWiki 1.20.2
- PHP 5.3.19 (apache2handler)
- MySQL 5.1.30

Comment: Sorry for asking the obvious, but what type is the property compound number?

Answer (score 0):

It think you have to set

```
    $smwgQEqualitySupport=SMW_EQ_NONE;
```

See [Help on $smwgQEqualitySupport](http://semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Help%3a%24smwgQEqualitySupport)